# How to give Jupyterhub access to hive tables through spark in EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hive, jupyter, amazon-emr, jupyterhub

The default installation of JupytherHub in EMR has no access to the Hive context in  Spark. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To grant spark access to the Hive context, you need to edit the livy.conf file (/etc/livy/conf.dist/livy.conf) like this

```
livy.repl.enableHiveContext = true
```

and then restart your notebook and the livy service, following the instructions [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restart-service-emr/), basically:

```
sudo stop livy-server
sudo start livy-server
```

An easy way to check if it's working, is to check for the databases on your spark notebook:

```
spark.sql("show databases").show
```

Yo may want to configure this on the EMR booting time, by using the standard configuration features of the EMR, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html